# Multiprocessing with PySpark in Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, multiprocessing

My current python script is below and runs locally with 6 cpu cores.

Can I convert it to PySpark and run it in Hadoop cluster, where I can specify `cores` to be `500`?

I have one thousand file to be downloaded so I would like to fire up paralleled processes as many as possible.

Please also be aware that my function is trying to connect to a data source and download the data file.

```
pool = Pool(cores=5)
pool.map(myfunction, arg_list)
pool.close()

def myfunction(args)
    (url,account,password,output_file_name) = args
    page = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(account,password), timeout=None)
    tables = lh.document_fromstring(page.content)
    rows = tables.xpath('//table[@id="Report1_Grid1"]/tr')
    body = [[td.text for td in rows[rowindex]] for rowindex in range(1, len(rows))]           
    tbl = pd.DataFrame(body)
    pd.DataFrame.to_csv(output_file_name)
```

Comment: Is the downloading or the processing your bottleneck?

Comment: You have already said that in your post, no need to repeat it. @syntonym's question was different

Comment: Yes, you can use Spark. What have you tried?

Comment: @desertnaut I added my comments back to the main question. Now I deleted my comments so it's easily for everyone to see. My bottleneck is on local pc I can't run too many processes in parallel. I want to run 1000 processes at the same time so I can complete the downloading within 1 minutes instead of 200 minutes (1000 files/5 processes).

Answer (score 0):

Just running this on a Hadoop cluster will not really change anything. I assume here that the PC you are currently running on and the cluster are in the same network and the server you are downloading from is not. Then you proably spend most of your time waiting for the bytes to physically arrive over the wire, and throwing more *computational power* at it will not change anything.

If your downlink is saturated you can't really change anything. If you have multiple locations (maybe you have multiple datacenters) then you could run in each location one downloader, do the processing and then aggregating in a single location.

If the uplink of the server are the problem (or the servers just don't want to give you more bytes/s) and you want to download from multiple servers (or the server is "tricked" to give you more bytes/s if you have multiple connections) you can simply run more requests, but again you don't really need a cluster for that. Just increase the your pool size, one request does not saturate one cpu core in this IO case. If the process overhead kills performance you can try something like [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

What could also happen is that your network card or the ethernet cable you plug into it is saturated, but your network could actually give you more downlink. In that case running on the hadoop cluster would actually improve the speed, but hogging a hadoop cluster to not actually use the computational power is not really a nice thing to do. Just find one (or 2 or maybe 3) servers that are well connected and download from there, possibly with something like grequests or a much larger pool.